# Не переведена фраза о поднятии вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В [истории вопроса](/posts/2775/revisions), поднятого Духом, отображается пункт

> Bumped by Community user

[image: Bumped by Community user]

Comment: У вас же есть учётка в Transifex? Почему бы просто не перевести строку?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у меня есть? о_О Впервые об этом слышу. Раньше не было.

Comment: я думал, что все "бывалые" участники уже завели себе. Так присоединяйтесь )

Comment: [string on Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/83658777?q=Bumped%20by%20Community%20user)